# How to get current record for each day

Tags: sql-server

if I have following database records

```
DATE        ITEMNAME

2014-02-10  A
2014-02-10  B
2014-02-10  C
2014-02-11  D
2014-02-11  E
2014-02-11  F
2014-02-11  G
2014-02-11  H
2014-02-12  I
2014-02-12  J
2014-02-12  K
2014-02-12  L
2014-02-13  M
2014-02-13  N
```

How to return the cumulative stock balance for every day so it would return something like this:

```
DATE        Total
2014-02-10  3
2014-02-11  8
2014-02-12  12
2014-02-13  14
```

Comment: Why 2014-02-11 has StockCount = 8 instead of 5?  Is it cumulative (ie. 5 + all previous days)?

Comment: @wdosanjos correct, how to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.  It gets the distinct dates from your table, then counts the number of entries that fall on or before each date.

```
WITH
CTE_Dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE
    FROM [TableName]
)
SELECT DATES.DATE,
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM CTE_Dates DATES
INNER JOIN [TableName] STOCKS
    ON DATES.DATE >= STOCKS.DATE
GROUP BY DATES.DATE
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL 2012 or SQL 2014, you can try the following.  Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f6cd/1/0).

```
 SELECT 
     [DATE], 
     SUM(COUNT(ITEMNAME)) OVER(ORDER BY [DATE] 
                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                               AND CURRENT ROW) AS StockCount
  FROM MyTable
  group by [DATE];
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew about the `ROWS` filter in window functions.  Thank you for that.